# Fastapi route that accepts a list of dictionaries as form data and testing using postman

Tags: python, postman, fastapi

I am having issues in creating a fastapi route that accepts this type of sample input as `form-data`

```json
{
    "name": "John Doe",
    "total_bill": 2000,
    "items": [{
                "item_name": "Baseball Bat",
                "item_code": "ABC",
                "item_image": null,
            },
            {
                "item_name": "Tennis Racket",
                "item_code": "XYZ",
                "item_image": tennis_racket.jpg,
            },
            {
                "item_name": "Basketball",
                "item_code": "PQR",
                "item_image": baskbetball.png,
            }
            ]
}
```

The main question is -- How to send this list of dictionaries which also has an optional file upload into the fastapi route function as a parameter?

And how do I test this via postman? I am unable to figure out how to send nested elements as form-data using postman. Most solutions seem to be outdates so any help (and screenshots of how you're sending the input to postman) would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why form-data instead of JSON ?

Comment: Probably because of the optional file upload, but you can't automagically send associative arrays / maps through Form data as far as I know - so you'll have to implement that yourself from serialized JSON or through some other syntax trick for your POST variables (like PHP's foo[]`).

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)